# How can I use addEventListener in Class EcmaScript6?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I use EcmaScript6 and don't know how to apply addEventListener in a Class. 
I tried declaring a var out of the Class to call the method EventListener and got an Error :/. I also tried addEventlistener inside of the Class and I can't.

The errors in console, is because I'm try again new alternate.

Don't know solution problem. how add the event listener ?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
class Design{
transition(clickea, up, down){
    this.clickea = clickea;
    this.up = up;
    this.down = down;
    let cont = 0;
    let focus = document.getElementById(clickea);
    let content = document.getElementById(up);
    let content2 = document.getElementById(down);
    if(cont == 0){
        content.style.transform = "translateY(-1000%)";
        content2.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
        cont++;
    }else{
        content.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
        content2.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
        cont--;
    }
}
}

const design = new Design();
let enlance = document.getElementById('sign');
enlance.addEventListener('click', desgin.transition(enlance, loguin, 
registro));
```

Google console

```
eventos.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at Design.transition (eventos.js:11)
at eventos.js:24
```

or

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
class Design{
transition(clickea, up, down){
    this.clickea = clickea;
    this.up = up;
    this.down = down;
    let cont = 0;
    let focus = document.getElementById(clickea);
    let content = document.getElementById(up);
    let content2 = document.getElementById(down);
    focus.addEventListener('click', function(up,down){
        if(cont == 0){
            content.style.transform = "translateY(-1000%)";
            content2.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
            cont++;
        }else{
            content.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
            content2.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
            cont--;
        }
    });

}
```

}

```
const diseño = new Design();
let enlance = document.getElementById('sign');
let loguin = document.getElementById('loguin');
let registro = document.getElementById('registro');
diseño.transition(enlance, loguin, registro);


eventos.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Design.transition (eventos.js:10)
    at eventos.js:29
transition @ eventos.js:10
```

My question is, how i can use listener in the template method Class.

Comment: You’re calling the event callback, you need to pass in a function reference.

Comment: First of all, if you want to set up event listeners like that, then your call to `design.transition(...)` must return a function. Secondly, you need to decide what your parameters are going to be. In the second example, you're calling `document.getElementById(clickea)` but `clickea` is *already* an element, namely `document.getElementById('sign')`.

Comment: What you are describing has nothing to do with classes. You are using `addEventListener` and `getElementById` incorrectly, and you would have the same problem if you didn't use a class. In the first case you are calling the function instead of passing it do `addEventListener`. In the second case you are passing a value to `getElementById` that is not a string, and thus `getElementById` returns `null`.

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mevycbzh/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

It looks like you're seeing this error because your class is expecting a string, but you're providing a DOM chunk.

Your code is essentially doing this...

```
document.getElementById(document.getElementById('sign'));
```

If you just provide strings to `transition()` you should be good.

Regarding your actual question

> How can I use addEventListener in Class EcmaScript6?

A class is really no different than a function, its just a way to store data/functionality. You can have a method on the class that gets a piece of DOM or a adds a listener to a piece of DOM, but you can't put a listener directly on the class. As it sits right now, it doesn't look like you are even trying to do that though. Your class simply stores some logic and procedural DOM code which is totally valid.